# In this plumbing code illustration, what are the meanings of "SH" "WC" "BT" "LAV", etc?

Tags: plumbing, basement

The image below, taken from [this plumbing code page](http://bsj.iccsafe.org/june/inside_icc/pmg_plumbvents_part_3.html), has an "SH" going to the middle pipe with the trap in it. Does anyone know what the "SH" stands for, or the "BT" and "WC" ones for that matter?

[image: code image]

The reason I ask is it seems to match the layout of some roughed in pipes coming out of my basement floor I asked about [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3693/how-can-i-verify-where-the-pipes-in-my-basement-go). I thought maybe knowing this will help me confirm what I have.

Comment: any of the top links here: https://www.google.com/#q=wc+sh+lav+bt+plumbing+acronyms

Comment: The first result doesn't make sense. It would have toilets (W.C.= water closet) on either side of a shower?

Comment: in the drawing, the WC's do not have traps ... actually, friends have exactly that, one 8x12 room with his/hers vanities/sinks/toilets/windows on either side, with a 4x6 shower in the middle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shamefully stolen from ArchToolbox's webpage of Plumbing and Fire Protection Abbreviations.
[This is a link to that page.](http://archtoolbox.com/representation/abbreviations/44-plumbabbrev.html)

... found by using google to search for these 6 terms: `wc sh lav bt plumbing acronyms`.
[This is a link to that google search.](https://www.google.com/#q=wc+sh+lav+bt+plumbing+acronyms)

```
AP    Access Panel                    HW    Hot Water 
BT    Bath Tub                        HWR   Hot Water Return      
BWV   Back Water Valve                HWS   Hot Water Supply      
CFH   Cubic Feet per Hour             ID    Inside Diameter       
CFM   Cubic Feet per Minute           INV   Invert                
CI    Cast Iron                       IW    Indirect Waste        
CLDI  Cement Lined Ductile Iron       MECH  Mechanical            
CO    Cleanout                        MSB   Mop Service Basin     
CONC  Concrete                        NC    Normally Closed       
CP    Chrome Plated                   NO    Normally Open         
CTE   Connect to Existing             OD    Outside Diameter      
CW    Cold Water                      OED   Open End Drain        
CWR   Cold Water Return               PIV   Post Indicator Valve  
CWS   Cold Water Supply               PLBG  Plumbing              
DCVA  Double Check Valve Assembly     PSI   Pounds per Square Inch
DF    Drinking Fountain               RPBP  Reduced Pressure Backflow Preventer
DIA   Diameter                        SA    Shock Absorber                        
EL    Elevation                       SH    Shower                     
ELEV  Elevation                       SHWR  Shower                     
EWC   Electrical Water Cooler         SK    Sink                       
FCO   Floor Cleanout                  SS    Soil Stack, Stainless Steel
FEC   Fire Extinguisher Cabinet       TLT   Toilet                            
FHV   Fire Hose Valve                 TS    Tamper Switch                      
FLR   Floor                           TW    Tempered Water        
FP    Fire Protection                 TYP   Typical               
FS    Flow Switch                     U     Urinal                
FT    Foot or Feet                    V     Vent                  
FV    Flush Valve                     VB    Vacuum Breaker        
GALV  Galvanized                      VS    Vent Stack            
GI    Grease Interceptor              VTR   Vent Through Roof     
GPF   Gallons per Flush               W     Waste                 
GPM   Gallons per Minute              WC    Water Closet (Toilet) 
HC    Handicapped                     WS    Waste Stack
```