# When cutting concrete for basement plumbing, how do you handle rough framing?

Tags: plumbing, basement

I'm going to be doing some cutting of the slab in my basement in order to put a bathroom in. There is plumbing under the slab and a pit with a tank in it, but it is probably 30 feet from where I want the bathroom. I understand I need to saw the floor, but there is roughed in load bearing stud walls in place (see [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3693/how-can-i-verify-where-the-pipes-in-my-basement-go) for actual pics if necessary).

I need to go through/under these walls, so what do I do when I reach them? Cut the footers?

Comment: how deep a trench is needed? how deep is the foundation wall+footing that are *under* the slab that is *under* the 2x load bearing wall?

Comment: deep enough for a 3" waste line. These are interior walls. At least a foot away from perimeter walls at all times.

Comment: If that is a load bearing wall, I bet that directly underneath the wall, under the slab, you will discover a foundation wall with a footer.

Comment: The basement was roughed in by the builder, probably 8 rooms in 2500 square feet. I say they are all load bearing because they have double 2x4 headers, which I understand to be the standard indication of load bearing. If that's true, would they go to all that trouble to do as you describe with the foundation?

Comment: I am guessing you are talking about double top plates, which is not an indication that it is load bearing ...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_plate  ... and ... http://www.thebuildingcodeforum.com/forum/residential-foundation-codes/6689-thickened-slabs-interior-load-bearing-walls.html ... and  ... http://www.arcxl.com/architects/detail?type=Spread+Footing+Detail

Answer (score 1):

One option is don't cut under the walls. Cut up to a couple of inches away from the wall and stop. Continue a couple of inches past the other side of the wall. Then you can just dig under the slab "bridge".